# Persisting GridView data across PostBacks?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, persistence

Alright, so here's my basic ASP.NET page setup: I've got a page with a GridView that has ContentTemplates in it. You can add a row and edit/remove rows at any time. There's a "New" button that creates a new row.

All of this data is bound to custom data objects. So if I have a GridView of "People" and each row has "FirstName", "LastName", and "Gender" (with TextBox and DropDown controls), I then have a "Person" object which has public properties for "FirstName", "LastName", etc. I have the binding set up correctly, and I can push data into the GridView from the object, and I persist the object with the Session variable. My page lifetime structure looks something like this:

- `Page_Load`: Loads the `List(Of Person)` from `Session()`
- Any events fire, and modify the `List(Of Person)`.
- After any event, the `List(Of Person)` gets saved back into `Session()`, and is then DataBound to the GridView (and any subsequent fields are also DataBound, such as the DropDownList.

My question is: Whenever I fill in rows in the GridView, and then add a new row (there is no database saving going on whatsoever), my fields clear out and don't persist across PostBacks. So, how can I persist my custom data objects with databinding across postbacks?

Comment: Where does the Page_Load first get its `List` of `People`?  If it always gets it from the `Session`, where does the `Session` first get it from?

Comment: If it doesn't exist, a new one is created and filled in with default values. I've debugged and checked that it's getting the object from `Session()` - it is.

Comment: Does a `PostBack` occur when adding a new row to the `GridView` or are you doing that on the client side?  Have you been able to verify that the newly added `Person` are in the `Session List` after a new `Person`/`GridView` line is added?

Comment: Yes, a `PostBack` occurs when you add a new row, and yes, new `Person` objects are getting added to the list, as well as the `GridView`.

Comment: Ok, that sounds like a great start.  This sounds a lot like a question that I asked a while ago.  So the user adds a new row to the `GridView`, causes a `PostBack` and the newly entered values aren't there anymore, right?

Forgive me if this sounds redundant:  do the newly added `Person` objects actually contain the data entered by the user?

Also, check this out: [Add New Row to GridView Without DataBind](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/273288/add-new-row-to-gridview-without-databind).

Comment: No, they don't. When the `PostBack` happens, the data that was entered into the text boxes in the GridView get reset to their defaults, and nothing gets "written" into the data objects. I don't do any manual "saving" of the data (I don't read the GridView's state or anything like that, because I thought ASP did all that persistent state stuff for you).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out myself. I just needed to handle the `TextChanged`, `SelectedIndexChanged`, etc. events and then save the new data into my custom objects there. Makes sense now that I think about it.

Thanks for everyone's help.

Answer (score 1):

Work with your custom data objects in the Pre_Init event.

Save your data the ViewState, not a session.  This way you ensure you aren't loosing the session, hence your work.

Comment: Session and ViewState act in the same manner, their only difference is when data that's stored inside them gets discarded (Session persists across multiple pages). Other than that, and since I'm working on only one page, it doesn't matter.

Comment: They don't act in the same manner, but ok - it's your design.  You asked for an opinion and help.