# Persisting Checkbox State when Paging Gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview, checkbox, rendering

In a nutshell, I am trying to maintain the *CheckBox* state on a *GridView* while paging. I am successfully tracking the *CheckBox* states in the *ViewState* (using an *ArrayList* on the row IDs) and I can successfully perform an action on all the checked rows on multiple pages.

However, once I go to a new page and then page back, the checked CheckBoxes are no longer checked (though the row ID still exists in the ArrayList in the ViewState). I have to assume this has something to do with the page life cycle.

I have read the entire **ASP.NET Page Life Cycle Overview** and tried binding the GridView in the PreRender event (and not binding the GridView at all) which didn't work either. All the examples I found online were loading the GridView DataSource from code behind using a DataTable filled from a SQLDataAdapter. I am using a DataSourceID (from a SQLDataSource) assigned directly to the GridView.

I still can't seem to determine why this is failing. Thanks in advance for your time.

ASPX Page

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="sdsAdminIntakes" runat="server" CancelSelectOnNullParameter="false"
    Connectionstring="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MyAppSiteDB %>"
    ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MyAppSiteDB.ProviderName %>"
    SelectCommand="admin_intakes_search"
    SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="specialist_id" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="caller_name" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="case_number" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="case_status" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>

<asp:GridView ID="grdAdminIntakes" runat="server"
    DataKeyNames="intake_id" DataSourceID="sdsAdminIntakes"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowSorting="True"
    AllowPaging="True" PageSize="20">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chkAll" />
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chkIntake" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:BoundField DataField="specialist_full_name" HeaderText="Current Specialist"
            SortExpression="specialist_full_name" >
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="caller_name" HeaderText="Caller"
            SortExpression="caller_name" >
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="case_number" HeaderText="Case #"
            SortExpression="case_number" >
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="cmp_status" HeaderText="Case Status"
            SortExpression="case_status" ItemStyle-CssClass="case_status" >
        </asp:BoundField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

ASPX.VB Page

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not IsPostBack Then
        grdAdminIntakes.DataBind()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub grdAdminIntakes_PageIndexChanging(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewPageEventArgs) Handles grdAdminIntakes.PageIndexChanging
    GetCheckboxState()
    grdAdminIntakes.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex
    grdAdminIntakes.DataBind()
    SetCheckboxState()
End Sub

Private Sub GetCheckboxState()
    Dim lstArray As ArrayList
    If ViewState("SelectedRecords") IsNot Nothing Then
        lstArray = DirectCast(ViewState("SelectedRecords"), ArrayList)
    Else
        lstArray = New ArrayList()
    End If
    Dim chkAll As CheckBox = DirectCast(grdAdminIntakes.HeaderRow.Cells(0).FindControl("chkAll"), CheckBox)
    For i As Integer = 0 To grdAdminIntakes.Rows.Count - 1
        If chkAll.Checked Then
            If Not lstArray.Contains(grdAdminIntakes.DataKeys(i).Value) Then
                lstArray.Add(grdAdminIntakes.DataKeys(i).Value)
            End If
        Else
            Dim chk As CheckBox = DirectCast(grdAdminIntakes.Rows(i).Cells(0).FindControl("chkIntake"), CheckBox)
            If chk.Checked Then
                If Not lstArray.Contains(grdAdminIntakes.DataKeys(i).Value) Then
                    lstArray.Add(grdAdminIntakes.DataKeys(i).Value)
                End If
            Else
                If lstArray.Contains(grdAdminIntakes.DataKeys(i).Value) Then
                    lstArray.Remove(grdAdminIntakes.DataKeys(i).Value)
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next
    ViewState("SelectedRecords") = lstArray
End Sub

Private Sub SetCheckboxState()
    Dim currentCount As Integer = 0
    Dim chkAll As CheckBox = DirectCast(grdAdminIntakes.HeaderRow.Cells(0).FindControl("chkAll"), CheckBox)
    chkAll.Checked = True
    Dim lstArray As ArrayList = DirectCast(ViewState("SelectedRecords"), ArrayList)
    For i As Integer = 0 To grdAdminIntakes.Rows.Count - 1
        Dim chk As CheckBox = DirectCast(grdAdminIntakes.Rows(i).Cells(0).FindControl("chkIntake"), CheckBox)
        If chk IsNot Nothing Then
            chk.Checked = lstArray.Contains(grdAdminIntakes.DataKeys(i).Value)
            If Not chk.Checked Then
                chkAll.Checked = False
            Else
                currentCount += 1
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5542500/persisting-gridview-data-across-postbacks)

Comment: I followed your link and read the entire post, but I am not having issues persisting data while paging, I am having issues rendering the checked checkboxes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several more hours of research, I was finally able to get this working by moving the **SetCheckboxState()** out of the *grdAdminIntakes_PageIndexChanging* event and into the *grdAdminIntakes_DataBound* event.