# Is it possible to add new row in gridview without databind? ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, gridview

Is it possible to add new row in gridview without again databind to gridview.

Comment: You can insert a tr with tds using JQuery...

Comment: There are some workarounds using which you can do this. See this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/273288/add-new-row-to-gridview-without-databind

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the DataTable as the Data source, first you add a new to the data table and then set this altered datatable as datasource of grid view.